# How to calculate this integral $\int \exp( C_0 + C_1 x + C_2 x^2 + C_3 \exp(x)) dx$

Tags: calculus

I model the occurrences of some events by a Poisson process and assume the intensity is $\exp({\bf X\beta+Zb})$.
Where $\beta$ is the fixed effect and $\bf b$ is the random effect.
The data ${\bf D}={D_i}$ and $D_i$ is the set of time points of events observed in $i$-th observation.
Therefore, the likelihood function is in the following form:

$L({\bf\beta},{\bf b})=f({\bf D|\beta},{\bf b})=\prod_i e^{-\lambda_i}\prod_{ij} \exp({\bf X}_i\beta+{\bf Z}_i{\bf b})=\prod_c \exp(C_{c0} + C_{c1} b_c + C_{c3} \exp(b_c)) $

Where $b_c$ is the effect of the $c$-th level of the random effect (I only consider one random effect), $C_{ci}$ can be calculated from $\bf D$ and $\bf X\beta$. The optimization objective of mixed-effect model (ML criterion) is

$L({\bf\beta},{\bf\theta})=\int f({\bf b|\theta}) L({\bf \beta},{\bf b})  \text{d} {\bf b}.$

Where $\theta$ is the variance vector of random effects, $f(b|\theta)$ is the pdf of a multivariate normal distribution $\text{N}({\bf O},\text{diag}([\theta_1^2 \, \theta_2^2 \, \cdots \, \theta_q^2]))$, and it introduces $C_2 x^2$ into the integral in the title.

I can calculate the integral without $C_2 x^2$, by replacing $\exp(x)$ with $u$. But it seems unsolvable with $C_2 x^2$. I currently use numerical integration but it is computational intensive.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: To integrate $x^2e^x$, do it by parts, twice. After the first time you should end up needing to integrate a multiple of $xe^x$.

Comment: Perhaps you can complete the square or factor the quadratic